# In an Excel chart: how to "copy" chart line format from one series to another using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

For some x and y such that SeriesCollection(x) exists and SeriesCollection(y) exists, I am trying to do the following:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(x).Format.Line = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(y).Format.Line
```

But, that gives me an error: "object doesn't support this property or method". How can I copy the line format of one series from a chart, to another series in the chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate through each property of .Format.Line

(It's confusing to use X and Y as variables indicating series, since X and Y conventionally refer to data of those series.)

```
Set srsA = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(A)
Set srsB = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(B)

srsA.Format.Line.ForeColor = srsB.Format.Line.ForeColor
srsA.Format.Line.Weight = srsB.Format.Line.Weight
```

etc.